# Working with multiple workspaces in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, workspace

Sorry but I can't find documentation about this...

If I want to use more than one workspace in Alfresco, how can I specify the workspace to use?

For example, to access a node, I use an url like this:

workspace://SpacesStore/32da316f-9d2a-4e57-a28b-89d86bff6584

If I have various workspaces (A and B)... How can I difference one from another with this url?

And on the code side... when I use Alfresco API Java operations, I authenticate with user and password (with getAuthenticationService().authenticate method). And do something like, for example, a query to search a node (TYPE:"{mymodel}exp" AND PATH:"/app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:mydir").

My question is the same... How can I specify one or other workspace to search in A or B? Has a different spacestore?

Comment: What do you mean by "workspace"? Different Tenants? And what version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: I'm using Alfresco 4.1.6. I have a big volume of documents and a lot of folders on a same level, and I'm trying to balance the tree. I don't know if is possible to use various workspace, and distribute the folders on there. Or maybe use different user homes and each user have an own user home.

Comment: A question about this... If I do a query searching for metadates, and each user have an own folder created on User Homes, Alfresco search on all the folders? Or only on the user folder?